# Does mockery in the workplace help with employee bonding

Tags: professionalism, ethics, unprofessional-behavior

I have a few questions regarding the workplace as I am quite new.

The employees in the company do not really treat each other with 'respect'. My colleagues mock each other in the workplace during working hours with impolite names in a dialect. The company has English as the spoken language but most of the employees do not comply to that. I could understand the mockeries as I could speak the dialect. Is this their way of bonding? From what I see, I think it is working as I could see that they are close to each other. Could anyone share their views and opinions regarding this matter as whether you experience these things on a daily basis.

So, to sum it up, I would like your opinions and experiences on a few matters.

1. Why is it that the employees call each other mocking names and does it help to bond? (I think this is considered informal working behavior)
2. Is there a way to bond with employees without being 'rude' to each other and to portray a professional image?

Thank you all so much for reading this post and if you could provide constructive opinions regarding these matters would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: VTC - Opinion based answers.

Comment: Depends on country and area. Especially people from East Asia can be surprised about seemingly rude interaction amongst Westerners which is perfectly friendly. I am not talking about bullying, but a general informal interaction style. Nonetheless, if OP does not fee good with this, perhaps this is not the right fit.

Comment: If you have to ask ...

Answer (score 4):

That kind of thing is Ok if everyone thinks it's funny. Sometimes that's the case. Sometimes it's not, and then the harmless fun suddenly becomes bullying. So I would stay away from it.

If staying away makes you a target for those colleagues, then we have exactly the situation of bullying that I talked about.